# In Node, JavaScript case problem, windows vs mac

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm finding that we have dev's on windows that are checking in code that works even though it has file name casing errors like:

```
import speakers.js
```

instead of

```
import Speakers.js
```

Which is correct. On windows, it works, Mac it does not. What's the best way to insure that windows devs don't check in problem code like this?

Comment: That probably depends on your version control system and *not* on nodejs or javascript

Comment: It's not just Mac vs. Windows, it's all UNIX-like OS's vs. Windows. Windows (NT) systems might be the only OS's that do this.

Answer (score 2):

#### Use a linter

Linters are programs that validates that your source code complies with some rules. A linter may forbid the use of the `var` keyword, or may enforce that a semicolon is present at the end of a line.

In javascript, [the most common linter is eslint](https://eslint.org/). It is reasonable easy to setup and most code editors play well with it.

There is a specific eslint plugin that checks that some rules are enforced in `require` and `import` calls: [eslint plugin dependencies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-dependencies). It enforce that files exist or that file names are/are not case sensitive, so this plugin should do the trick for you. (However, I never configured it by myself. I believe most cli apps from javascript frameworks include it in their default configuration).

If you setup this properly, developers will see warnings in their editors when they try to use mayus within import or require sentences, and the command `eslint` will fail if run.

#### Use javascript hooks to ensure no invalid commit is pushed to the repository

Using git hooks, you can enforce that `eslint` (or any other linter or command) must pass in order for a commit to be added to a repository.

[This article explain how to do this with javascript](https://medium.com/@Sergeon/using-javascript-in-your-git-hooks-f0ce09477334) (disclaimer, I'm the author), and provides some context on the matter.

Also there is [the husky package](https://github.com/typicode/husky) that easily allows you to setup git hooks to prevent bad commits. The good thing about using husky is that the hooks can get pushed to the repository, so new developers on the project don't need to manually setup their `.git/hooks/` files.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely an OS problem. Didnt try yet but you can activate the windows case sensitive option to avoid import errors. You have to execute the following command:

```
fsutil.exe file SetCaseSensitiveInfo C:\folder\path enable
```

Be advice:

- Linux Subsystem should be enabled:
  Run the following command as Administrator in PowerShell to enable this optional feature:

`Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux`

- It doesnt affect subfolders so a recursive script would be needed

Comment: this is why I have a rule for my teams that all files are to be lowercase only

Comment: Thats the fastest option, but I like classes in UpperCamelCase :(

Comment: windows does not know what upper case files even are. On windows This.txt and this.txt are the same, but on *nix and OSX they are completely different files.

Comment: I know, thats the problem. If I use `import Speakers.js` for `speakers.js` I wont notice any error in my enviroment, but my import wont work for my coworkers using different OS